# Google Charts - viz 1.1 - IE11 - Chart not displayed due to error: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'contains''

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, google-visualization

Using new Google charts, using the SVG charts, viz 1.1, when running a Stacked bar chart using multiple series, i'm getting a

```
Chart not displayed due to error: 'Object doesn't support property or method 'contains'' Full error object follows.
```

then

[image: Screen shot of debugger]

Using the ng-google-charts wrapper, these are the report options.

```
$scope.casesChartObject = {
                "type": "Bar",
                "displayed": true,
                "data": data.chartmodel,
                "options": {
                    "title": "...",
                    "isStacked": "true",
                    "fill": 20,
                    "displayExactValues": true,
                    "vAxis": {
                        "title": "Infection rate", viewWindowMode: "explicit", viewWindow: { min: 0 }, format: '0.00',
                        "gridlines": {
                            "count": 12
                        }
                    },
                    "hAxis": {
                        "title": "h labal"
                    },
                    series:data.series

                },
                "formatters": {}
            };
```

It works on Chrome and FF, and it's not easy in IE to find the source of the error.

Has anybody had this problem?

TIA

Comment: There can be several reasons for this error - when it works in Chrome and FF but not IE try this -> http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/object-doesnt-support-this-property-or-method/bb8b8be5-270c-44fd-a692-8e55d8ce499b?auth=1 (basically clear the cache, perhaps somehow your code conflicts with something in the cache)

Comment: can you provide a demo?

Comment: i'll try to separate it out for demo dr molle

Comment: It's a [bug](https://github.com/google/google-visualization-issues/issues/2039) in current version...